# Safari Frames Invisible Scrollbar

Tags: html, safari, scroll, frames, frameset

I'm working on a website that uses not just frames, but frames within frames (ew, I know, but I don't get to choose).  It actually works OK most of the time, but I'm running into a problem with some of the frames within frames in Safari (only).

Some of the two-deep frames render in Safari with a small space on the right-hand side of the frame - I think it's just the ones with scroll set to "no", but fiddling with the scroll settings hasn't fixed it yet.  It basically looks like there should be a scroll bar there, but there isn't.

I've been working on this awhile and tried a lot of things: changing the heights of the rows, changing the scroll settings, adding a `colls='100%'` tag, changing the heights of the contents of the frames, as well as checking to make sure widths are set to 100% throughout.  Nothing's fixed it so far.

Does any one know what's happening here?

Here's the basic gist of the code and some screenshots - please forgive the lack of proper quotes; it still renders and fixing them all in this codebase would be a losing battle:

```
<html>
    <frameset id=fset frameborder=0 border=0 framespacing=0 onbeforeunload="onAppClosing()"  onload="onAppInit()" rows="125px,*,0">
        <frame src="navFrame.html" name=ControlPanel marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no noresize>
        <frame src="contentFrame.html" name=C marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no>
        <frame src="invisiFrame.html" name=PING marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 noresize>
        <noframes><body>Tough luck.</center></body></noframes>
    </frameset></html>
```

Inside that second frame (named "C" and with src of "contentFrame") is this:

```
 <HTML>
    <HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
    <frameset rows="48px,*,28px" border=0 frameborder=0 framespacing=0>
       <frame src="pageTitle.html" name=Title marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 noresize scrolling=no frameborder=0>
       <frame src="content.html" name=ScreenBody marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0>
       <frame src="submitBar.html" name=ContextPanel marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no noresize>
    </FRAMESET>
 </HTML>
```

The frames that are troublesome are the first frame (named "Title" with src of "pageTitle.html") and the last frame (named "ContextPanel" with src of "submitBar.html") both have their widths set to 100% and heights are either 100%, not set, or a value less than or equal to their row height.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: image showing site in Firefox and Safari, with sections labeled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is how Safari draws scrollbars when there is not enough space to draw the entire scrollbar widget set. You should set `overflow: hidden` in the CSS for the `body` of any frame/page you don't want to scroll. Note that Safari doesn't entirely obey these rules (or `scroll="no"` on the element) in that you can actually scroll the element by drag-selecting its contents, if there is in fact content beyond the visible area.

Answer (score 2):

The title and submit frames showing scroll bars can have the html body tag scroll="no"

```
<body scroll="no">
```

so irrespective of a frame or normal rendering, there would be no scrollbar.

Comment: I didn't try this (since I'm tryinnng to stick to CSS whenever possible), but it definitely pointed in the right direction. Thanks!